# Access the vector state and updating it using near-sdk-rs

Tags: rust, nearprotocol

I am trying to update the vector, this my code so far.

```
use near_sdk::collections::Map;
use near_sdk::collections::Vector;
#[near_bindgen]
#[derive(Default, BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize)]
pub struct ProfileDetails {
    profile_tags: Map<String, ProductList>,
}

#[near_bindgen]
#[derive(Default, BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize, Debug)]
pub struct Product {
    product_name: String,
    product_details: String,
}

#[near_bindgen]
#[derive(Default, BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize)]
pub struct ProductList {
    products: Vector<Product>,
}

#[near_bindgen]
impl ProfileDetails {
    pub fn set_profile(&mut self, product_name: String, product_details: String) {
        let account_id = String::from("amiyatulu.test");
        println!("{}", product_name);
        let p = Product {
            product_name,
            product_details,
        };
        let id = account_id.clone().into_bytes();
        let mut id_products = ProductList {
            products: Vector::new(id),
        };
        id_products.products.push(&p);
        self.profile_tags.insert(&account_id, &id_products);
    }

    pub fn push_product_to_profile(&mut self, product_name: String, product_details: String) {
        let account_id = String::from("amiyatulu.test");
        let p = Product {
            product_name,
            product_details,
        };
        let my_products_option = self.profile_tags.get(&account_id);
        match my_products_option {
            Some(mut my_products) => {
                my_products.products.push(&p); //It doesn't update the state
                self.profile_tags.insert(&account_id, &my_products);
                println!("Hello myproducts push");
            }
            None => println!("Can't get the profile tag"),
        }
    }
```

The problem is this statement doesn't update the state of the blockchain.

```
my_products.products.push(&p); //It doesn't update the state
```

So, I have inserted the vector again in this statement.

```
self.profile_tags.insert(&account_id, &my_products);
```

Is this the right way? Does it cause repeated storage of ProductList's product vector? How to get the vector state and update it?

Complete code [here](https://github.com/amiyatulu/nearprotocol_learning/blob/7fb0e556b94c95c73a1d3b9ffe76a5c140fa620e/contract/src/lib.rs)

Comment: According to the `near-sdk-rs` Github README they have a Discord (you can find it [here](https://near.org/community/)). You might have better luck getting immediate answers if you ask your questions there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rust, the result of `match` is frequently immutable. So in your example:

```
Some(mut my_products) => {
```

although having `mut`, does not mean it's mutating (changing) the value that's ultimately associated with `self`.

So your approach with `self…insert` is correct. This is a common approach in Rust generally. There are exceptions to this rule in Rust that may highlight what's going on.

For instance, in the standard collection `HashMap` there's `get_mut` (as opposed to `get`) which returns a mutable reference. You can see [in the Rust docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get_mut) that this returns `Option<&mut V>` while the [HashMap's get method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get) returns `Option<&V>`.

Now we can look at the [docs for the NEAR Vector](https://docs.rs/near-sdk/0.10.0/near_sdk/collections/struct.Vector.html#method.get) `get` method to see that `get` returns `Option<T>` which is immutable.

So again, your approach looks good here to me.

In terms of modifying the Vector, I believe you're likely going to want to use [the Set collection](https://docs.rs/near-sdk/0.10.0/near_sdk/collections/struct.Set.html) instead, but I dislike it when StackOverflow questions change the subject like that. So below I've provided a test you can add that demonstrates some of the Vector usage I believe you're looking for.

```rust
    #[test]
    pub fn modify_update_product_list() {
        let context = get_context(vec![], false);
        testing_env!(context);

        // first product
        let product_one = Product {
            product_name: "toothbrush".to_string(),
            product_details: "electric and sleek".to_string(),
        };
        let product_two = Product {
            product_name: "soap".to_string(),
            product_details: "smells like teen spirit".to_string(),
        };
        let product_three = Product {
            product_name: "shampoo".to_string(),
            product_details: "natural mint oils".to_string(),
        };

        let mut profile_detail = ProfileDetails::default();

        let mut product_list = ProductList {
            products: Vector::new(b"products".to_vec()),
        };
        println!("Corner Store: adding toothbrush and soap…");
        product_list.products.push(&product_one);
        product_list.products.push(&product_two);

        let shop_name = "Corner Store".to_string();
        profile_detail.profile_tags.insert(&shop_name, &product_list);

        // Say we come back later to the saved state
        // Get the product list from Corner Store
        match profile_detail.profile_tags.get(&shop_name) {
            Some(mut current_product_list) => {
                // add shampoo product
                println!("Corner Store: Inserting shampoo…");
                current_product_list.products.push(&product_three);
                profile_detail.profile_tags.insert(&shop_name, &current_product_list);

            },
            None => {
                // if this were outside of tests we'd have:
                // env::log(b"Didn't find shop name");
                println!("Didn't find shop name")
            }
        }

        let product_list = profile_detail.profile_tags.get(&shop_name);
        assert!(product_list.is_some()); // can also have is_none()

        println!("Corner Store: Listing products");
        for product in product_list.unwrap().products.iter() {
            println!("Corner Store: Product {:?}", product);
        }

        // Sold out of soap, remove it
        println!("Corner Store: Removing index 1, which should be soap");
        // Consider using something like Set
        // https://docs.rs/near-sdk/0.10.0/near_sdk/collections/struct.Set.html
        let current_product_list = profile_detail.profile_tags.get(&shop_name);
        assert!(current_product_list.is_some(), "Couldn't find shop");

        // Remove and get object at index 1
        let soap = current_product_list.unwrap().products.swap_remove(1);
        println!("Corner Store: Removed index 1 which was {:?}", soap);
    }
```